# Joining large tables in ClickHouse: out of memory or slow

Tags: join, clickhouse, materialized-views

I have 3 large tables (>100 GB with millions of rows each): `events`, `page_views`, and `sessions`. These tables are connected via 1-n relationships, see table setup below. I'm trying to create a denormalized `events_wide` table that contains a row for each event, where the corresponding `page_views` and `sessions` columns are joined. The idea is to eliminate the joins needed for complex analytics queries, since these joins are slow.

I created a materialized view `events_mv` which joins the `page_views` and `sessions` table to the events table. Whenever a new event is inserted into `events`, the materialized view should insert a row into `events_wide`, joining the page_view and session automatically. However, when I insert a single new event, the query either doesn't finish or terminates with an out of memory error.

Even running this simple join query from `events` to `page_views` results in an out of memory error: `Memory limit (for user) exceeded: would use 99.21 GiB`. I use a ClickHouse Cloud production instance with 24+ GB RAM:

```sql
SELECT
    -- Select columns from events and page_views
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN page_views AS p ON p.property_id = e.property_id AND p.id = e.page_view_id
LIMIT 3;
```

I tried different primary key orderings for the 3 tables `(property_id, created_at, id)` vs  `(property_id, id, created_at)`, different join algorithms (`partial_merge`, `auto`, `grace_hash`), `ANY LEFT JOIN`, without success. Maybe using UUIDs instead of numeric IDs is part of the problem, but I can't change the UUIDs unfortunately.

This is my table setup with the `(property_id, id, created_at)` primary keys:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events
(
    id UUID,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    property_id Int,
    page_view_id Nullable(UUID),
    session_id Nullable(UUID),
    ...
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
PRIMARY KEY (property_id, id, created_at)
ORDER BY (property_id, id, created_at);

CREATE TABLE page_views
(
    id UUID,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    modified_at DateTime('UTC'),
    session_id Nullable(UUID),
    ...
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(modified_at)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
PRIMARY KEY (property_id, id, created_at)
ORDER BY (property_id, id, created_at);

CREATE TABLE sessions
(
    id UUID,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    modified_at DateTime('UTC'),
    property_id Int,
    ...
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(modified_at)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
PRIMARY KEY (property_id, id, created_at)
ORDER BY (property_id, id, created_at);


CREATE TABLE events_wide
(
    id UUID,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    property_id Int,
    page_view_id Nullable(UUID),
    session_id Nullable(UUID),
    ...
    -- page_views columns
    p_created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    p_modified_at DateTime('UTC'),
    ...
    -- sessions columns
    s_created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    s_modified_at DateTime('UTC'),
    ...
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
PRIMARY KEY (property_id, created_at)
ORDER BY (property_id, created_at, id);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_mv TO events_wide AS
SELECT
    e.id AS id,
    e.created_at AS created_at,
    e.session_id AS session_id,
    e.property_id AS property_id,
    e.page_view_id AS page_view_id,
    ...
    -- page_views columns
    p.created_at AS p_created_at,
    p.modified_at AS p_modified_at,
    ...
    -- sessions columns
    s.created_at AS s_created_at,
    s.modified_at AS s_modified_at ,
    ...
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN page_views AS p ON p.property_id = e.property_id AND p.id = e.page_view_id
LEFT JOIN sessions AS s ON s.property_id = e.property_id AND s.id = e.session_id
SETTINGS join_algorithm = 'partial_merge';
```

Comment: if you wan't JOIN in large tables ClickHouse is not the best way

try https://www.starrocks.io/ for it

Comment: CH has problems with joins.  see TPCH  testing. https://celerdata.com/blog/clickhouse-vs.-starrocks-a-detailed-comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ClickHouse doesn't have a proper optimizer, so the right tables of the join require to be filtered before performing a join. Otherwise, full tables will be pushed to memory to perform the join causing the issues you're experiencing.

Using the example you've provided:

```sql
WITH events_block AS (
    SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 3
)
SELECT e.*, p.* FROM events_block AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM page_views
    WHERE (property_id, id) IN (
        SELECT property_id, page_view_id FROM events_block
    )
) AS p ON p.property_id = e.property_id AND p.id = e.page_view_id;
```

This could seem weird if you think about single join operation but materialized views are processed in blocks, this will prevent moving to memory full right tables every single time.

So rewriting the materialized view as follows will do the trick:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_mv TO events_wide AS
SELECT
    e.id AS id,
    e.created_at AS created_at,
    e.session_id AS session_id,
    e.property_id AS property_id,
    e.page_view_id AS page_view_id,
    ...
    -- page_views columns
    p.created_at AS p_created_at,
    p.modified_at AS p_modified_at,
    ...
    -- sessions columns
    s.created_at AS s_created_at,
    s.modified_at AS s_modified_at,
    ...
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM page_views
    WHERE (property_id, id) IN (
        SELECT property_id, page_view_id FROM events
    )
) AS p ON p.property_id = e.property_id AND p.id = e.page_view_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM sessions
    WHERE (property_id, id) IN (
        SELECT property_id, session_id FROM events
    )
) AS s ON s.property_id = e.property_id AND s.id = e.session_id
```

Comment: So the `SELECT property_id, id FROM events` in the subqueries will select only from the block of events to be inserted, not the whole events table? Then this might work indeed, I'll try it next week, thx!

Comment: Exactly, all references to events table inside that materialized view will be referring to the block being inserted. Cool let me know if works!

Comment: This actually works and denormalisation is pretty fast, too! It's still important to not insert too many rows (events) in one query, to avoid memory errors. I guess I could always use a different join algorithm less memory use but lower speed.

Comment: However, I still get memory errors if the event insert batch exceeds about 100k rows in my case. I need to find a solution to control the batch size or find better approach.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid expensive joins in this case, what about having the single denormalized super table "events_wide" with all the columns but use three different materialized views?

Each Materialized View would insert columns for each table to the "events_wide" and the columns not present with zeros or nulls.

For instance:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_to_events_wide TO events_wide AS
SELECT
    e.id AS id,
    e.created_at AS created_at,
    e.session_id AS session_id,
    e.property_id AS property_id,
    e.page_view_id AS page_view_id,
    ...
    -- page_views columns as null or zeros
    
    ...
    -- sessions columns as null or zeros
    
    ...
FROM events AS e

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW page_views_to_events_wide TO events_wide AS
SELECT
    e.id AS id,
    e.created_at AS created_at,
    e.modified_at AS modified_at,
    ...
    -- events columns as null or zeros
    
    ...
    -- sessions columns as null or zeros
    
    ...
FROM page_views AS e

...
```

Then you have a single table with all records you can aggregate or perform the analysis you need without joins.

Comment: The goal is to aggregate events and filter them based on the corresponding session data.  E.g. count events where the corresponding session active duration exceeds a threshold. So we need the events and their corresponding page view and session data in the same row, otherwise we can't filter the events.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the memory footprint manageable, you can try breaking the JOIN process down into two join operations.
You can achieve it by chaining materialized views:

1. First join `events` with `page_view` in a dedicated MV, let's say `events_with_pv`
2. Then join the `events_with_pv` with `sessions` into the final MV `events_wide`

You can use `join_algorithm='auto'` and let ClickHouse automatically decide which algorithm to use.
Materializing the intermediate state will allow to reduce the size of the state needed to compute the JOIN. Something to keep in mind in that you want the right table of your JOINs to be the smallest.

Comment: Unfortunately, a single left join already exceeds memory, because the tables are quite large. Using join_algorithm='auto' is simply too slow. ClickHouse has no primary keys to identify single rows, only granules. So joins over large datasets based on UUIDs seem  very inefficient.